# Sort files to directories by date and filename

Tags: linux, bash

I got filenames that always start with Y-M (e.g. 2014-01)
All files right now are in one directory, 
And I want to split them to a root year directory (2014) and sub-directories by month (01,02 etc..)

This is what I was doing so far manually:

```
   find /dirlocation/ -name "2014-12*" -type f -exec mv {} /pathtocp/2014/12 \;
```

And I would change the date and cp directory manually each time..

Can someone please help me with a bash script for it to happen automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: try using a for loop in bash script. For a every year that you have, run through all the months.

Comment: Do months prior to October have a leading 0? After the month is there another dash, or does other text start?

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes, months start with a leading 0. after the month there is another dash of date in number (i.e. 2014-12-21)

Comment: Do you want the final moved files to contain year and month, as initially or not?

Comment: Hi chatraed, as stated in the question, the filenames already contain the year and month

Comment: My question is, after those files are moved to the yyyy/mm/filename path, do you still want filename to contain the yyyy_mm prefix?

Comment: Sorry I missed your question, yes I still need it to contain the prefix. the original filename should be left intact.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer according to your expectations.

Comment: Just a quick follow up on that, can you please explain with your method, how can I change the find to a specific directory? for example "/root/dir"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "./[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}.*"); do
    y=${f:2:4}
    m=${f:7:2}
    mkdir -p "$y/$m" && mv "$f" "$y/$m/$f"
done
```

> ASSUMPTIONS:
>
> - The bash script is run from the path the files reside in

Comment: Since it also covers the fact that destination directory might now exist and is robust to future years as well, that's what I chose to go with. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
for i in 2014 2015; do
  for j in `seq 1 12`; do
    j=`printf %.2d $j`          #to convert 1 to 01
    find /dirlocation/ -name "$i-$j*" -type f -exec mv{} /pathtocp/$i/$j \; #assuming this sentence is correctly written in question.
   done;
done;
```

Comment: Hi Rkholiya, thanks for the edit! I will give it a try and update